# Elastic: Are Analyzers only for `text` type fields?

Tags: database-design, optimization, elasticsearch, index-design

Most of the documentation about Elastic Analyzers assumes that you NEED an Analyzer and so the documentation talks mostly about how Analyzers work and the differences between the different Analyzers.

**But I had trouble finding authoritative documentation answering the question: are Elastic Analyzers only for `text` type fields?**